# PHP File Copy Error Permission or Configuration

Tags: configuration, permissions

I need help, can’t copy file to www folder

Few days ago I moved my site from windows hosting to Linux
and got this error.

**Info:** 
I have site and need to upload images, so I write simple PHP script to move images from tmp to images folder.

```
$word = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);           

if (isset($_FILES["ImgSrc"]["name"])) {
    $ImagesTmp->ImgSrc = $word . $_FILES["ImgSrc"]["name"];

    if($_FILES["ImgSrc"]["error"] != 0)
        return;

    move_uploaded_file($$_FILES["ImgSrc"]["tmp_name"], "../images/" .  $ImagesTmp->ImgSrc);
}
```

**Problem:**
    I get error - failed to open stream: Permission denied in ……

**More Info:**
1)  **www** folder permission is 777 (including sub folders) – permissions aren’t issues here ?! 
2)  I created test folder **/var/www_test** and change my script use this folder as destination folder and script worked as should be – permissions aren’t issues here ??!
Seem that I can’t copy files to **www**. Feels like some process is blocking to create file from PHP.
I think its configuration problem, but can’t find problem .

OS is Fedora 24
Apache/2.4.23 (Fedora) PHP/5.6.23
user: apache 
www folder permission 777 (including sub folders)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem, SELinux is here!

If someone have similar problem us this link

https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/